# Get a single element in a set

Tags: java

I have a difficult question for me to explain. In some words I have a `Set<object>` and I need to get elements one by one (i.e. i need to get just an element of the set), but i can't if out of a for cycle. For example here i can get everything:

```
for (Iterator<Object> i = fh.getParsed().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        HTTPFormat next = (HTTPFormat) i.next();
        System.out.println(next.getIP());
    }
```

but if i'd like to print just an element (i.e. System.out.println(trial.getParsed().get(0)). To be understood I say that I have a Set called "parsed" in a class as attribute, and a getter for parsed. I don't know if i was as clear as well, but i hope yes. If you've doubts never mind to ask! :) Thankyou!

Comment: So if you want to print the first why don't you do the code you suggest, or not use a loop?

Comment: Generally speaking sets are not ordered so if your set contains more then one element there is no guarantee which element you will get if you ask for the "first" one. In particular if you iterate and take the first element in the iteration, there is no guarantee that that is an element that was added first to the set

Answer (score 4):

If you want a single element of the `Set`, you can write

```
HTTPFormat element = (HTTPFormat) fh.getParsed().iterator().next();
```

This will return the first element of the `Set` according to the iteration order. If this is an ordered set (such as `TreeSet`), the first element according to that order will be returned. If it's a `HashSet`, it would return an arbitrary element (which depends on the `hashCode()` implemention of `HTTPFormat` and the current size of the `Set`).

Note that it will throw an exception if the `Set` is empty.

P.S. I wouldn't use a `Set<Object>`. If your `Set` contains `HTTPFormat` elements, use a `Set<HTTPFormat>` to avoid the unsafe cast.

Comment: Or just print it avoiding the need for a cast. +1

Comment: @PeterLawrey True, but that would only work if the OP wants to print the entire element (as oposed to printing `getIP()` as in the code snippet in the question).

Comment: i was thinking to add the same info you just added , +1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java8+, you could use `findAny` or `findOne` to retrieve one element from collection, like below

```
HTTPFormat element = (HTTPFormat) fh.getParsed().stream().findAny().orElse(defaultObject());
```

`find*` returns Optional object,which is safe to use and you can pass/get default element if the collection is empty.

if you need the first element you can use `findFirst` in case of ordered collection